# The time after 23:59:59 is 01:00:00, but I want 01:00:00 after 24:29:59

Tags: python, datetime, time, clock, time-format

The time after 23:59:59 is 01:00:00, but I want 01:00:00 after 24:29:59

Program:

```
seconds = 56
minutes =59 
hours = 23
import time
from turtle import *
setup()
t1 = Turtle()
while True:
     t1.clear()
     t1.write(str(hours).zfill(2) + ":" + str(minutes).zfill(2) + 
":" + str(seconds).zfill(2))
     seconds = seconds + 1
     time.sleep(1)
     if seconds == 60:
         seconds = 0
         minutes = minutes + 1
     if minutes == 60:
         minutes = 0
         hours = hours + 1
     if hours == 24:
         hours = 0
         hours = hours + 1
```

Output:
23:59:59/
01:00:00/
01:00:01

Output I want:
24:29:59/
01:00:00/
01:00:01

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect: the time after 23:59:59 is 00:00:00, not 01:00:00

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to solve the above yourself and whenever you face difficulty in doing so please post the script along with the difficulty you face. read this to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Prune you don't know that. He might be making a clock for a game in a made up world, where time flows differently. Hence the 24:30 reset maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Your clock doesn't follow the rules of normal time, but if you really want what you ask, add an if statement for the hour reset

```py
         if hours == 24 and minutes == 30:
             hours = 1
             minutes = 0
```

Comment: Make that a compound condition (instead of separate `if` statements), and you get an up-vote.

Comment: Got It Sir! Really Great!! This is exactly what I want..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your clock to count the midnight hour as 24, rather than 00, and then to move on to 01 as normal. You can do this, just just need to change where you reset your hours. Instead of resetting `24` to `0`, you want to reset `25` to `1`:

```
while True:
    t1.clear()
    t1.write(str(hours).zfill(2) + ":" + str(minutes).zfill(2) + 
":" + str(seconds).zfill(2))
    seconds = seconds + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes = minutes + 1
    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0
        hours = hours + 1
    if hours == 25:              # change here
        hours = 1                # and here
```

There's no reason to reset to zero and then increment, it's *more* clear if you set directly to 1.